# How to use selenium.type if there are many labels with same notation?

Tags: java, selenium-rc

i'm working with Selenium RC and coding with Java , my problem is the selenium.type ,My screen contains  many labels with the same notation so when i use the method :

```
 selenium.type("//span[text()=\""+remplace+"\"]/following-   sibling::input#form:blocConfigurations:configurations:0:parametrage:options:"+ind.get(ii)+"",configuration.getString(listTypMetier.get(il))))
```

even if the locator is not the same it always keeps typing in the same field.

Comment: Can you post your html snippet here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try adding some id's or classes to your labels/fields if that's an option. That selector looks pretty long and complex if you are only wanting to type some text into an input field. If not, is there any reason you have done it the way you've shown in your question?